# Combine NVARCHAR column with the result of a SUM in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by

How can I combine a `NVARCHAR` column with the result of a `SUM` in SQL Server?

I have tried

```
dbo.tblCurrencies.strCurrencySymbol + dbo.tblItems.dcUnitPrice * dbo.tblItems.intItemQuantity
```

Which tells me:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

So I tried

```
dbo.tblCurrencies.strCurrencySymbol + CAST(SUM(dbo.tblItems.dcUnitPrice * dbo.tblItems.intItemQuantity) AS NVARCHAR)
```

AND

```
CAST(dbo.tblCurrencies.strCurrencySymbol + SUM(dbo.tblItems.dcUnitPrice * dbo.tblSalesOrderItems.intItemQuantity) AS NVARCHAR)
```

Both tell me

> Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a group by clause.

Any more information you need just let me know I'll put it up.

EDIT:

The query

```
SELECT        dbo.tblItems.fkOrder, dbo.tblCurrencies.strCurrencySymbol + SUM(dbo.tblItems.dcUnitPrice * dbo.tblItems.intItemQuantity) AS TotalPrice
FROM          dbo.tblCurrencies RIGHT OUTER JOIN
              dbo.tblOrders ON dbo.tblCurrencies.pkCurrency = dbo.tblOrders.fkPaysInCurrency RIGHT OUTER JOIN
              dbo.tblItems ON dbo.tblOrders.pkOrder = dbo.tblItems.fkOrder
GROUP BY      dbo.tblItems.fkOrder
```

EDIT 2:

Ok I managed to solve it by adding `dbo.tblCurrencies.strCurrencySymbol` into the group by and using `CONCAT()`

My query now looks like this:

```
SELECT        dbo.tblItems.fkOrder, { fn CONCAT(dbo.tblCurrencies.strCurrencySymbol, CAST(SUM(dbo.tblItems.dcUnitPrice * dbo.tblItems.intItemQuantity) AS NVARCHAR(10))) } AS TotalPrice
FROM          dbo.tblCurrencies RIGHT OUTER JOIN
              dbo.tblOrders ON dbo.tblCurrencies.pkCurrency = dbo.tblOrders.fkPaysInCurrency RIGHT OUTER JOIN
              dbo.tblItems ON dbo.tblOrders.pkOrder = dbo.tblItems.fkOrder
GROUP BY      dbo.tblItems.fkOrder, dbo.tblCurrencies.strCurrencySymbol
```

It also works without the `CONCAT()`

```
SELECT        dbo.tblItems.fkOrder, dbo.tblCurrencies.strCurrencySymbol + CAST(SUM(dbo.tblItems.dcUnitPrice * dbo.tblItems.intItemQuantity) AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS TotalPrice
FROM          dbo.tblCurrencies RIGHT OUTER JOIN
              dbo.tblOrders ON dbo.tblCurrencies.pkCurrency = dbo.tblOrders.fkPaysInCurrency RIGHT OUTER JOIN
              dbo.tblItems ON dbo.tblOrders.pkOrder = dbo.tblItems.fkOrder
GROUP BY      dbo.tblItems.fkOrder, dbo.tblCurrencies.strCurrencySymbol
```

Not sure which is better though?

Comment: Use [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), Concat or cast the *number* to text. As for the second error, it has nothing to do with concatenation. There's a problem with the rest of the query, specifically the GROUP BY clause. Post the *full* query

Comment: Honestly I usually do, I realise I haven't in this question that's my bad sorry. I can't see the link you posted it doesn't seem to work but I did wonder what the implications of not declaring a length would be.

Comment: @Pete for now, post the rest of the query. The second error has nothing to do with concatenation. One of those fields is *not* included in the GROUP BY clause

Comment: @marc_s that link is broken. The correct one is https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: FYI, putting the schema name before a column name is deprecated, and your SQL *will* stop working one day. It's strongly recommended you use (good) aliasing.

Comment: I'd recommend [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) over `FORMAT` any day, @PanagiotisKanavos. Especially as the OP simply wants to put the currency character at the start.

Comment: @Larnu I always forget - I rarely format values in SQL, *especially* money

Comment: I don't put the schema name myself it adds it in when creating a view in ssms but I will always use aliasing going forward, thank you for the tip!

Comment: I managed to get the result I wanted and have edited the question with what I did. Now I am just wondering which method is better and why really, or maybe it's not a good method at all. I am still learning so all feedback helps.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: thanks for pointing that out! I'll make sure to use the proper link in the future

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server there's a concept named [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). It's there in cases such as these when two different data types need to be combined because there needs to be a method to decide on what the data type of the final output will be.

In your case you're combining NVARCHAR and NUMERIC data types and as NUMERIC has the higher precedence the approach it takes is to try and convert your text data into a number which it can't do, hence the error.

If you need the conversion to run in a way other than defined in the normal precedence order then you need to explicitly make the conversion yourself with either CAST or CONVERT. In your case you need to multiply the needed numbers, convert those to text and then concatenate the currency symbol.

Subsequent errors come from using fields that are neither within an aggregate or specified in the Group By of your select statement. Adding you currency field in there should resolve the other issue assuming you can't have one order with multiple currencies involved.

Putting it all together gives you the following:

```
SELECT
     Orders.fkOrder,
     Currencies.strCurrencySymbol
      + CAST(SUM(Items.dcUnitPrice * Items.intItemQuantity) AS varchar(50)) AS TotalPrice
FROM dbo.tblItems AS Items
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblOrders AS Orders
    ON Items.fkOrder = Orders.pkOrder
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblCurrencies AS Currencies
    ON Orders.fkPaysInCurrency = Currencies.pkCurrency
GROUP BY Orders.fkOrder, Currencies.strCurrencySymbol
```

Comment: This was exactly what it was, soon as I added `dbo.tblCurrencies.strCurrencySymbol` to the Group By it worked fine. I was updating my question with what i had done when you posted this so I didn't see it. I am now wondering weather I should use Concat() or not as it's working fine without it but then there could be a reason that I don't know about as to why I should use it.

Comment: There's not a lot of difference between the two approaches. CAST is potentially more flexible if you're making multiple combines. CONCAT on the other hand has the benefit of handling NULL values gracefully rather than setting the whole output result to NULL when one is encountered. It wouldn't surprise me if CONCAT was expanded out to CAST and ISNULL under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the query fragment that you have posted, I would try something along the lines of

```
dbo.tblCurrencies.strCurrencySymbol + 
    CAST(SUM(dbo.tblItems.dcUnitPrice * dbo.tblSalesOrderItems.intItemQuantity) AS NVARCHAR(x))
```

Points to note: the cast to `NVARCHAR` is done on the sum part only

`x` is the length of the `NVARCHAR` string that you wish to cast it to (make sure that it is wide enough to hold the largest value that the sum can return).

Using the schema name prior to the column name is deprecated.

Comment: `dbo.tblCurrencies.strCurrencySymbol + CAST(SUM(dbo.tblItems.dcUnitPrice * dbo.tblItems.intItemQuantity) AS NVARCHAR(10))` just gives me the error `Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a group by clause.` In my question I stated that i have tried that but I hadn't declared a length. The same error occurs when declaring a length also.